# apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: apache-2.2

I've never encountered this error before. And secondly I'd like to know how you folks debug your apache configurations.

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

In my Virtual Host configuration I do have these lines:

```
ServerName  example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

*(of course it has my actual info in there)*

So I guess my question is, why wouldn’t apache be able to determine my fully qualified domain name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check your `/etc/hosts` file. It should look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
a.b.c.d       www.example.com
```

The first line should already be there, you only have to add the second line with your values.

Comment: did you mean /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because you need to have "ServerName" declared outside vhost configuration, in the apache2.conf and the ServerName value declared in the /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the points already mentioned (`/etc/hosts` and the `ServerName` directive outside a vhost) it doesn't hurt to have the `hostname` value set properly for the system. Use the `hostname` command (as root or with sudo) to set it. (If you do this without doing the other two, the errors will continue, but it will replace "Using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName" with "Using [the value of `hostname`] for ServerName".