# Apache FQDN error

Tags: apache-2.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name](https://serverfault.com/questions/101164/apache2-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Starting Apache is giving this error:

```
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Can someone explain this error to me please?

Comment: you should search before posting. This is a duplicate of many other posts, such as: http://serverfault.com/questions/101164/apache2-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name

Answer (score 2):

That FQDN error is not a problem for apache, it is just a minor warning. You could run this server in production and it would make no difference.

If you google how to set up the FQDN there are tutorials for almost every flavor of linux. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=204360

Comment: so should i ignore this error or not???

Comment: yes, you can ignore the error.

Answer (score 2):

When using virtual hostnames and someone requests the IP instead of a hostname, Apache might use the `ServerName` setting to redirect clients to the correct URL.

Therefore, you should define the `ServerName` value. On Debian-based Apache 2 installations, you can do this in the file "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf", which should be empty by default. Just add

```
ServerName my.website.com
```

If you're only having Apache as development server, you can simply ignore the warning. Apache will use reverse DNS to lookup for requests to 127.0.0.1, for example, and thus automatically find out that the hostname is "localhost".

Another way is to edit the "/etc/hosts" file. That will work as well because of named reverse DNS lookup.