# vhost file not bring recognised by apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, configuration, virtualhost, mac

Hi sorry total noob to Apache and Macs here... feel the answer is really obvious but I've been looking for ages without success

I have the following lines in /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/mfoe/"
ServerName mfoe.cycle
</VirtualHost>
```

The httpd.conf file is including vhosts

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

So why when I run the command in terminal: $ httpd -S do I get:

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Alexs-  MacBook-Air.local for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

It looks like it's not reading anything in vhosts. Is it possibly anything to do with this error on restart?

```
Alexs-MacBook-Air:/ alex$ httpd -k restart
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Alexs-MacBook-Air.local for ServerName
httpd not running, trying to start
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Apologies if the answer is really stupid!

---

The full contents of httpd.conf

```
    #
    # Mac OS X / Mac OS X Server
    # The <IfDefine> blocks segregate server-specific directives
    # and also directives that only apply when Web Sharing or
    # server Web Service (as opposed to other services that need Apache) is on.
    # The launchd plist sets appropriate Define parameters.
    # Generally, desktop has no vhosts and server does; server has added modules,
    # custom virtual hosts are only activated when Web Service is on, and
    # default document root and personal web sites at ~username are only
    # activated when Web Sharing is on.
    #
    #
    # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
    # In particular, see 
    # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
    # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
    #
    # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
    # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
    # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
    #
    # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
    # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
    # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
    # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "log/foo_log"
    # with ServerRoot set to "/usr" will be interpreted by the
    # server as "/usr/log/foo_log".

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
    # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
    # at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
    # httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
    #
    ServerRoot "/usr"

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
    <IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
    Listen 80
    </IfDefine>

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
    # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
    # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
    # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
    # to be loaded here.
    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #
    LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
    LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
    LoadModule disk_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_disk_cache.so
    LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache2/mod_dumpio.so
    LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
    LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
    LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
    LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
    LoadModule substitute_module libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
    LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
    LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
    LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
    LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule cern_meta_module libexec/apache2/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
    LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
    LoadModule ident_module libexec/apache2/mod_ident.so
    LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
    LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
    LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
    LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
    LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
    LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
    LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
    LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
    LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

    #Apple specific modules
    LoadModule apple_userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir_apple.so
    LoadModule bonjour_module libexec/apache2/mod_bonjour.so

    <IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
    LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbd.so
    LoadModule authn_default_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
    LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_default_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_default.so
    LoadModule mem_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_mem_cache.so
    LoadModule dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_dbd.so
    LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
    LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
    </IfDefine>

    <IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>
    LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
    #LoadModule auth_digest_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest_apple.so
    #LoadModule encoding_module libexec/apache2/mod_encoding.so
    #LoadModule jk_module libexec/apache2/mod_jk.so
    LoadModule apple_auth_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_apple.so
    LoadModule spnego_auth_module libexec/apache2/mod_spnego_apple.so
    LoadModule apple_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_digest_apple.so
    #LoadModule python_module libexec/apache2/mod_python.so
    #LoadModule xsendfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_xsendfile.so
    LoadModule apple_status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status_apple.so
    </IfDefine>

    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User _www
    Group _www

    # 'Main' server configuration
    #
    # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
    # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
    # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
    # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
    #
    # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
    # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
    # virtual host being defined.
    #

    #
    # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
    # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
    # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
    #
    ServerAdmin you@example.com

    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    #ServerName www.example.com:80

    <IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>
    DocumentRoot /var/empty

    <IfModule mod_auth_digest_apple.c>
            BrowserMatch "MSIE" AuthDigestEnableQueryStringHack=On
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header add MS-Author-Via "DAV"
            RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https' env=https
            RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'http' env=!https
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_encoding.c>
            EncodingEngine on
            NormalizeUsername on
            DefaultClientEncoding UTF-8
    # Windows XP?
            AddClientEncoding "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/" MSUTF-8
    # Windows 2K SP2 with .NET
            AddClientEncoding "(Microsoft .* DAV\$)" MSUTF-8
    # Windows 2K SP2/Windows XP
            AddClientEncoding "(Microsoft .* DAV 1.1)" CP932
    # Windows XP?
            AddClientEncoding "Microsoft-WebDAV*" CP932
    # RealPlayer
            AddClientEncoding "RMA/*" CP932
    # MacOS X webdavfs
            AddClientEncoding "WebDAVFS" UTF-8
    # cadaver
            AddClientEncoding "cadaver/" EUC-JP
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /usr/share/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Header Set Cache-Control no-cache
    </Directory>
    Alias /webmail /usr/share/web/webmail.html
    Alias /changepassword /usr/share/web/changepassword.html
    Alias /profilemanager /usr/share/web/profilemanager.html
    Alias /webcal /usr/share/web/webcal.html
    </IfDefine>

    <IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
    <IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>
    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

    #
    # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
    # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
    # directory (and its subdirectories). 
    #
    # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
    # features.  
    #
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
    # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
    # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
    # below.
    #

    #
    # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
    #
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride None

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    </Directory>

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </IfModule>
    </IfDefine>
    </IfDefine>
    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    <FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>

    #
    # Apple specific filesystem protection.
    #
    <Files "rsrc">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </Files>
    <DirectoryMatch ".*\.\.namedfork">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </DirectoryMatch>

    #
    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedvhost
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
        LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" commonvhost

        <IfModule logio_module>
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
          LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinediovhost
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
        # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
        # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
        # logged therein and *not* in this file.
        #
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        #CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" combined
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
        # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
        # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
        # Example:
        # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

        #
        # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
        # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
        # Example:
        # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
        #
        # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
        # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
        # the filesystem path.

        #
        # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
        # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
        # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
        # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
        # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
        # directives as to Alias.
        #
        ScriptAliasMatch ^/cgi-bin/((?!(?i:webobjects)).*$) "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/$1"
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule cgid_module>
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock /private/var/run/cgisock
    </IfModule>

    #
    # "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
    # if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
    # If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
    # a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
    # or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
    # keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
    # text.
    #
    DefaultType text/plain

    <IfModule mime_module>
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types

        #
        # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
        # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #
        # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
        # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
        #
        #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
        #
        # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
        # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #
        # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
        # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddType text/html .shtml
        #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    #MIMEMagicFile /private/etc/apache2/magic

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
    #

    #
    # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
    # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
    # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
    # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
    # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
    # broken on your system.
    #
    #EnableMMAP off
    #EnableSendfile off

    TraceEnable off

    # Supplemental configuration
    #
    # The configuration files in the /private/etc/apache2/extra/ directory can be 
    # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
    # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
    # necessary.

    # Server-pool management (MPM prefork specific)
    StartServers 1
    MinSpareServers 1
    MaxSpareServers 1
    # ServerLimit and MaxClients support n% syntax which sets them to a
    # fraction of the current RLIMIT_NPROC limit. 
    ServerLimit 50%
    MaxClients 50%
    ListenBackLog 512
    MaxRequestsPerChild 100000

    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 15

    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    # UseCanonicalName: Determines how Apache constructs self-referencing
    # URLs and the SERVER_NAME and SERVER_PORT variables.
    # When set "Off", Apache will use the Hostname and Port supplied
    # by the client.  When set "On", Apache will use the value of the
    # ServerName directive.
    #
    UseCanonicalName Off

    #
    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    # ServerTokens
    # This directive configures what you return as the Server HTTP response
    # Header. The default is 'Full' which sends information about the OS-Type
    # and compiled in modules.
    # Set to one of:  Full | OS | Minor | Minimal | Major | Prod
    # where Full conveys the most information, and Prod the least.
    #
    ServerTokens Full

    # Optionally add a line containing the server version and virtual host
    # name to server-generated pages (internal error documents, FTP directory
    # listings, mod_status and mod_info output etc., but not CGI generated
    # documents or custom error documents).
    # Set to "EMail" to also include a mailto: link to the ServerAdmin.
    # Set to one of:  On | Off | EMail
    #
    ServerSignature On

    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid

    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    LockFile "/private/var/log/apache2/accept.lock"

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteLock /var/log/apache2/rewrite.lock
    </IfModule>

    # Language settings
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf

    <IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>
    # Multi    -language error messages
    #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

    # Fancy directory listings
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

    # User home directories
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf

    # Virtual hosts
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

    # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf

    </IfDefine>

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    <IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
    #Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    </IfDefine>
    <IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
            SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/etc/apache2/getsslpassphrase
            SSLSessionCache shmcb:/var/run/ssl_scache(512000)
            SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
            SSLMutex file:/var/run/ssl_mutex
            SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
            SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
            AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert crt
            AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl crl
    </IfModule>
    </IfDefine>

    <IfModule mod_jk.c>
            JKWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
            JKLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
            JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule php5_module>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
        <IfModule dir_module>
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
        Include /etc/apache2/other/*.conf
    </IfDefine>
    <IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>
        <IfDefine WEBSERVICE_ON>
            Include /etc/apache2/sites/*.conf
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
            Include /etc/apache2/sites/virtual_host_global.conf
            Include /etc/apache2/sites/*_.conf
            Include /etc/apache2/sites/*__shadow.conf
        </IfDefine>
    </IfDefine>
```

Output of ps auxwwww - I have uploaded to 
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:292b

Comment: Were you able to get httpd running?

Comment: I think I solved it by just deleting the page that says "It Works!" Once I'd done that it loaded wordpress etc. Even in the subfolders it wouldn't load anything but now it does! I'd love to know why it did that... bizarre. Im still not sure why httpd -S shows no congifuration file because it's definitely processing it now

Comment: update, no its broken again :(

Comment: Is this question resolved? Did you try [looking at other questions](http://serverfault.com/q/101164/39440)?

Answer (score 5):

Is https.conf a typo in your question?

Anyway, a reason why apache wont start : You are not root.

Apache won't start because it tries to listen on port 80, and [regular users can't bind ports below 1024](https://serverfault.com/questions/268099/bind-to-ports-less-than-1024-without-root-access).

Try starting apache as root and post the next errors.

Comment: Ok great thanks (and yeah that was a typo!) Now when I restart I just get

    httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Alexs-MacBook-Air.local for ServerName

Comment: This is just a warning. Apache works? (go to http://127.0.0.1 )

Comment: Yes! Cool, but I still can't get to http://mfoe.cycle as defined in httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Try adding 127.0.0.1 mfoe.cycle in /etc/hosts (if mfoe.cycle has to be reachable from any other comp, you might want to add a dns entry). httpd -S still produces the same output?

Comment: I've already got that entry in the hosts file too :(

Comment: This is the actual output Alexs-MacBook-Air:/ alex$ sudo httpd -S
Password:
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Alexs-MacBook-Air.local for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK

Comment: Looks like your vhost is not included. Did you double check that httpd.conf includes /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf ?

Comment: I checked, it's definitely there!!! It says:
# Virtual hosts 
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: May i ask you to post or paste bin httpd.conf  and the output of ps auxwwww?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on OS X 10.8.3:

open httpd.conf

```
$ sudo nano private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and find the line that reads:

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

(for me it was line 166)

Changing this line to:

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerName localhost
```

and then restart Apache

```
$ sudo apachectl graceful
```

removed the "httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name" complaint.

I hope this works for you too.